# Добавление к форматированному коду кнопки копирования

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Не часто, но приходится копировать код из вопроса. Есть ли возможность в элемент, который отображает форматированный код добавить кнопку `Копировать`.

Думаю для вопрошающих данный функционал был бы тоже очень востребован.

Пример подобного функционала в *Wiki.js*:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мы как сообщество не можем менять движок сайта. Стоит предложить это на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этот функционал периодически запрашивается на разных Метах, включая хорошо принятый сообществом запрос еще далекого 2009 года:

- [Shortcut or button for copying posted code from Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32625/383809)

В ответах приведены прототипы нескольких вариантов реализации функционала, направленных конкретно на Stack Exchange.

К сожалению, эта функция пока не реализована, не принята к рассмотрению и не отклонена — то бишь находится в перманентом состоянии забвения. Возможно, объявленный мной конкурс даст толчок к чуть большей определенности (хотя предыдудщие "надцать" ни к чему не привели). [Поддержите запрос функционала на общей Мете вашим голосом](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32625/383809).

Также есть расширение на StackApps:

- [Select Code Block Buttons Script](https://stackapps.com/q/2553/61023)

которое добавляет кнопки копирования блоков кода с помощью пользовательских скриптов.

Comment: Мне больше понравилось это расширение https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295483/694203